# SwiftUI Animation Hitches Xcode Instruments

Tags: xcode, debugging, animation, swiftui, profiler

I'm encountering severe animation hitches and cannot figure out how to debug them. There are WWDC sessions on how to debug animation hitches in general. There, it usually comes down to some heavy task being executed on the main thread. However, in my case, there is no such call. Most of the hitches are Pre-Commit(s) latency hitches. I'm not too sure what that is. I'd appreciate anyone giving me some insights. When I try to get more details on what is taking all the computing time, I only see some SwiftUI code. I've also tried the view body tool, but it doesn't show any view recreations that could cause such hitches.

[image: Animation Hitches]
[image: Time Profiler]

Comment: It would be helpful to have some example code

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a lot of experience with this but i had the same problem. [This article](https://maheshsai252.medium.com/animation-hitches-in-ios-development-8363b400aeed) explained what the types of the hitches are. I had commit to render latency hitches and they were caused by some logic that was in the onAppear of a view. I hope this may help you too.